# Instead of exception handling, what about "success-handling"?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have a script that allows the user to create drafts or send emails from a sheets file. I'd like to send a toast to the user's gui upon success of the createDraft or sendEmail function, respectively. How can I do this? I've stumbled across [this help page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run), but it seems to only be for html-pages?

A sample line of my code:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, sub, null, {cc: seesee, bcc:beeseesee, htmlBody: body1});
```

I want to send a toast if this email was sent successfully, at least on the script-side of things. I guess maybe I could just write a toast call after the line, for if it doesn't return an error the code will keep executing and we can assume it was 'successful'? But I'm just wondering if there's a more thorough way of testing whether it sent successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sendEmail will throw an error if it fails to send so how about something like:

```
try {

  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, sub, null, {cc: seesee, bcc:beeseesee, htmlBody: body1});

} catch (error) {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().toast('Email send failed')
  return
}

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().toast('Email sent')
```

And you want to use MailApp.send().

Comment: Thanks! Why would I want to use MailApp instead?

Comment: "Changes to scripts written using GmailApp are more likely to trigger a re-authorization request from a user than MailApp scripts." - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

Comment: ok that's what I came across afterwards but left the comment in case there was something I was missing. thanks!